# Measuring current transducer output - differential or single ended?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, differential, isolation, transducer

I'm designing a front-end for an ADC that will be measuring the voltage of a hall effect current transducer.

I have been reading up on differential vs single-ended measurement, and have become a bit confused as to how differential measurements work in a case like this.

I need to filter out noise that will be imposed onto the signal from the transducer because the wiring is passing through an electrical distribution box that has AC.

What I don't understand is this: if I want to reject this noise by using a differential amplifier, do I need to have an isolated power supply powering the current transducer?  If not, then where do I make the ground connection in the *differential measurement* schematic, below?

Also, do I run all the wiring to the current transducer as a double twisted pair (i.e. all 4 wires?)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuANpf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**EDIT:**

The hall effect transducer that I'm thinking of using is [CSLT6B100](http://sensing.honeywell.com/index.php/ci_id/49803/la_id/1/document/1/re_id/0), which has a ratiometric voltage output of 2.5V ±1500mV over the range -100 to 100 A

It's block diagram is as follows:

[image]

and transfer function:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the Hall Effect sensor you are using? Without this information it's impossible to tell what your sensor has in terms of regulators and amplifiers in it. A Hall device by definition IS a differential sensor, but it's unlikely you have a raw device. Read this to gain an understanding: http://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Technical-Documents/AN27701-Hall-Effect-IC-Application-Guide.ashx

Comment: @JackCreasey I added the reference to the transducer I'd like to use in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the schematic above, where I wrote "Does this connect to Vss", the answer is yes.

The differential measurement will be between Vout and Vss, and will travel in a twisted pair to the inputs of the differential amplifier.